# If formula for formatting of cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a public function I am trying to run that looks at the formatting in column C and puts a value based on the formatting in column G with click of a command button. I would like the lines highlighted yellow to get a zero and those that have no interior and do not have a strikethrough to get a one. I have written the code below but when I click the command button nothing happens. Not sure if I have the code in the right spot or in the wrong syntax? Any and all help is appreciated.

```
Sub Resort()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim urng As Range
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim shCmt As Comment
Set ws = Worksheets("Workbench Report")
lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

ws.Select
ws.Range(Cells(2, "B"), Cells(Cells(2, "E").End(xlDown).Row, "G")).Sort _
key1:=ws.Range("E1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, Orientation:=xlSortColumns

ws.Columns("E:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit
ws.Columns("E:E").ColumnWidth = 6.86

ws.Select
For Each rng In ws.Range("C2:C" & lastrow)
If rng.Interior.Color = 65535 Then
If urng Is Nothing Then
 Set urng = ws.Range("E" & rng.Row)
Else
 Set urng = Union(urng, ws.Range("E" & rng.Row))
End If
End If
Next rng

If Not urng Is Nothing Then urng.copy

ws.Range("B" & Cells.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

ws.Range("H2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

ws.Range("B" & Cells.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 2).Select
Selection.Formula = "=IF(H2>0,COUNTIF(E:E,H2)-2,"""")"
Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Selection.copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ws.Range("B" & Cells.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(3, 2).Select
Selection.Formula = "=IF(H3>0,COUNTIF(E:E,H3)-2,"""")"
Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Selection.copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ws.Range("B" & Cells.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(4, 2).Select
Selection.Formula = "=IF(H4>0,COUNTIF(E:E,H4)-2,"""")"
Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Selection.copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ws.Range("B" & Cells.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(5, 2).Select
Selection.Formula = "=IF(H5>0,COUNTIF(E:E,H5)-2,"""")"
Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Selection.copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ws.Range("B" & Cells.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(6, 2).Select
Selection.Formula = "=IF(H6>0,COUNTIF(E:E,H6)-2,"""")"
Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Selection.copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ws.Columns("H").ClearContents

SendKeys ("{ESC}")

ws.Select
ws.Range("E2").Select
End Sub

Public Function ColorIndex(rng As Range) As Boolean

For Each rng In ws.Range("C2:C" & lastrow)
If rng.Interior.Color = 65535 Then
ws.Range("G" & rng.Row).Value = "0"
End If
Next rng

For Each rng In ws.Range("C2:C" & lastrow)
If rng.Interior.Color = xlNone And rng.Font.Strikethrough = False Then
ws.Range("G" & rng.Row).Value = "1"
End If
Next rng

End Function
```

Comment: How you call your function?

Comment: I have call ColorIndex in my Sub module

Comment: By clicking inside the margin of the VBA editor, you can enable a breakpoint, which will pause the execution of your VBA code. If this is the case, you are sure already that your code is executed. If not, you might need to investigate why your code is not executed.

Comment: The reason nothing happens is because you can't use a `Function` in this way. You either need to rewrite the UDF to work on only the supplied `rng` argument, or convert it to a Sub if you want to do the entire thing by the click of a button.

Comment: How do I rewrite it to work on only the supplied rng argument?... I have added the rest of the code that is under the command button sub to my question and took out the call line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said in my comment, you can't use a `Function` to act on multiple cells in the way that you've done. You have two options.

(a) Rewrite so that the function only acts on the cell supplied in the argument.
(b) Make a `Sub` instead, that you can call from the command button.

Here's how the function might look:

```
Function ColorIndex(rng As Range) As Boolean
    If rng.Item(1).Interior.Color = 65535 Then ColorIndex = "0"
    If rng.Item(1).Interior.Color = 16777215 And rng.Item(1).Font.Strikethrough = False Then ColorIndex = "1"
End Function
```

Put it in column G, like this: `=ColorIndex(C2)` and fill down.

Here's how the sub would look:

```
Sub ColorIndex(rng As Range)
    For Each r In rng
        If r.Interior.Color = 65535 Then ws.Range("G" & r.Row).Value = "0"
        If r.Interior.Color = 16777215 And r.Font.Strikethrough = False Then ws.Range("G" & r.Row).Value = "1"
    Next r
End Sub
```

The macro you assign to the command button:

```
Sub buttonColorIndex()
    Call ColorIndex(ws.Range("C2:C" & lastrow))
End Sub
```

EDIT: I know you didn't ask about it, but here's a suggestion for some other optimizations in your code.

You have a few paragraphs looking like this:

```
ws.Range("B" & Cells.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 2).Select
Selection.Formula = "=IF(H2>0,COUNTIF(E:E,H2)-2,"""")"
Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter Selection.copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Remove all of them and try this instead:

```
With ws.Range("B" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    For i = 2 To 6
        With .Offset(i, 2)
            .Value = ws.Evaluate("IF(H3>0,COUNTIF(E:E,H" & i & ")-2,"""")")
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Ahh ok so create a sub and call the sub in the original sub under the command button... gotcha thanks so much!

Comment: I'm getting an Invalid Next control variable reference in the sub ColorIndex code

Comment: Oops. I forgot to change two letters - it should be fixed now.

Comment: Code is running but I am only getting the zeros and not the ones. I dont think this a code problem though might be something in my excel file. Thanks though!

Comment: If I were to guess, it's because the criteria aren't being evaluated the way you expected. I'll try it out for myself and see what happens.

Comment: Replace `xlNone` with `16777215`. xlNone only works when you set the color, not when you retrieve it. On retrieval, you need to use the numerical code.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a suggestion to other parts of your code as well.